# Integrating Google MLKit and optimal way to return its results

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, image-segmentation, google-mlkit

I'm currently working on integrating Google MLKit into our app, and my approach involves treating the MLKit component as a black box, where I pass an image and receive a result in return. Following [MLKit's tutorial](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/selfie-segmentation/android), I have developed a simple script that can analyze a `media.Image` or `ImageProxy` image (along with its rotation value) and generate an output mask. However, I'm  not sure about the most efficient way to return the results without having excessive conversion overhead. Looks like our app prefers getting a `Surface` type as a return type for the results. Is it possible to return the results as a `Surface` object or something of same nature? What would be the optimal type closest to Surface for the results to return?

```
class YourAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
    Segmenter segmenter;
    public YourAnalyzer(Segmenter segmenter) {
        this.segmenter = segmenter;
    }

    @Override
    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy imageProxy) {
        @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
        Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
        if (mediaImage != null) {
            InputImage image =
                    InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
            // Pass image to an ML Kit Vision API

            Task<SegmentationMask> result =
                    segmenter.process(image)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(
                                    new OnSuccessListener<SegmentationMask>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(SegmentationMask segmentationMask) {
                                            // Task completed successfully

                                            ByteBuffer mask = segmentationMask.getBuffer();
                                            int maskWidth = segmentationMask.getWidth();
                                            int maskHeight = segmentationMask.getHeight();

                                            for (int y = 0; y < maskHeight; y++) {
                                                for (int x = 0; x < maskWidth; x++) {
                                                    // Gets the confidence of the (x,y) pixel in the mask being in the foreground.
                                                    float foregroundConfidence = mask.getFloat();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                            .addOnFailureListener(
                                    new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            // Task failed with an exception
                                            // ...
                                        }
                                    });
        }
    }
}
```